# systemd -- very unclear error msg/warning, "Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group..."

Tags: systemd, systemctl

When doing systemctl-status on an old application, we are now seeing this error/warning:

```
"systemd[1]: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acquired through unsafe symlink chain"
```

I tested to remove a symlink in the chain, but then got this instead:

```
"New main PID xxxxx does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing."
```

And when trying to examine the pid-file, it wasn't even created.

In spite of these errors/warnings, it seems the application is still working...
So I am not sure when this error started appearing, but I suspect it's started after some RHEL OS-upgrade in the last year(s).

Some intial googling didn't turn up much useful....

Where can I find an explanation of these messages?

What exactly is "unsafe"?

And what to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message sounds like you're using a stale PID-file which isn't being updated by your daemon and still contains a PID from many reboots ago.

> And when trying to examine the pid-file, it wasn't even created.

systemd **never creates** PID-files, it only *reads* them. It is the job of your daemon program to write its own PID there if you've decided that you need a PID-file.

If your daemon doesn't write a PID-file, do not use the `PIDFile=` option at all. (If it does, change the option to point directly at the PID file rather than going through several symlinks.)

> What exactly is "unsafe"?

"Unsafe symlink chain" means that there is a non-root-owned symlink which points to a root-owned file – which is considered unsafe as there's a risk of the non-root user potentially causing systemd to read an unexpected file (e.g. if /tmp/something.pid was symlinked to /etc/shadow, it could leak the contents of the target file through "parse error" messages). Use `namei -l <path>` to see this.

"Outside of service cgroup" is unsafe because if service 1 were allowed to claim a process belonging to service 2 as its main PID, it would be easy to trick systemd and/or the system administrator into killing the other service.

Systemd service tracking is strongly tied to kernel cgroups. Accepting an out-of-cgroup PID as the main process is unwanted as it'd cause confusing situations where a service is running but its cgroup is empty, or where two services share the same main PID.

Comment: Thanks you for enlightening reply, I start to see now what the issue is... :)

Comment: It was not an old/stale PID-file, though.
After adding some logging, I saw that the app start-script actually CREATES the PID-file, so apparently systemd REMOVES it after startup -- because "unsafe" I guess :(

Comment: It's certainly frustrating that systemd introduces such intrusive changes that stuff that worked on installation few years ago, suddenly gets broken after a routine RHEL patch-update.
One would expect more intelligable error msgs when such changes are introduced -- at minimum, a message with a link to relevant documentation should be required.

Comment: systemd does not create PID files and it does not remove PID files. That's the job of your daemon. If your daemon doesn't create one – don't bother with start-scripts, _just don't use a PID file in the first place._

Comment: well, I really cant explain the observed behavior in any other way than systemd removes the PID-file under these circumstances --- when I run the app start-script manually, the PID-files gets created and survives --- when I start it through systemd/reboot, I verify that the start-script CREATES the PID-file, but after startup it's just gone....

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's possible that it removes the pidfiles on service stop – which leads to the other problem of it thinking that your service has exited already. Why does your service use a start-script? Does the .service unit have the correct Type= for it?

Comment: It has: Type=simple

Comment: If the start-script feels the need to create a PID-file, then I assume it also sends the service "to background", in which case Type=simple would be wrong – it would need to be Type=forking.